# Connection and getting specific files from an FTPS using Azure Functions

Tags: ftp, azure-functions

is it possible to get the files in an FTPS using Azure Functions?

So what i'm looking for is being able to connecting to an FTPS and getting files that start with a special name and then process the file and return the content to a logic app for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes FTPS is possible in Azure Function.

For the reference purpose use

https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentFTP/19.2.2. Here is the code:

```cs
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            var client = new FtpClient(
                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FTP_HOST"),
                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FTP_USERNAME"),
                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FTP_PASSWORD"));

            var items = await client.GetListingAsync();

            foreach (var i in items)
            {
                log.LogInformation($"{i.Name} {i.Size}");
            }

            return new OkResult();
        }
```